# How can I select with least amount of nan values for a certain time period in panda?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, missing-data, data-preprocessing

I have dataset with quite a lot data missing which stores hourly data for several years. I would now to implement a seasonal filling method where I need the best data I have for two following years (2*8760 entries). This means the least amount of data missing (or least amount of nan values) for two following years. I then need then the end time and start time of this period in datetime format. My data is stored in a dataframe where the index is the hourly datetime. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
To make it a bit clearer I need to select all entries (values and nan values) from a time period of of two years (or of 2*8760 rows) where the least amount of nan values occur.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all the NAN values from your data by using `df = df.dropna()`

Comment: Thanks but I need a full two year period including nan values. I will then interpolate/estimate this value at a later state.